# XML Message sent over MSMQ does not include encoding

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm writing an application that uses MSMQ and I'm encountering a problem specifically to do with encoding attribute for the XML declaration tag.

I'm constructing the message as below:

```
string xmlmsg = reqText.Text;
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlmsg));

xdoc.InsertBefore(xdoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), xdoc.DocumentElement);

Message _msg = new Message();

_msg.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xdoc.OuterXml));
reqQueue.Send(_msg, "XML Request");
```

The console output of ***xdoc.OuterXml*** reveals that the encoding is included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

But when I send the message over MSMQ, the encoding attribute gets removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The Message.Formatter property matters.  The default is XmlMessageFormatter, it surely has its own idea about how the body should be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the encoding was wrong. Here is the simplified code that actually worked:

```
        Message _msg = new Message
        {
            Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(),
            BodyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_xmlmsg))
        };
        reqQueue.Send(_msg, "XML Request");
```

Instead of ASCII, it needed to be Unicode.

Comment: Encoding can not be wrong or correct as long as you're working with DOM document. Encoding takes effect once you're exporting your DOM model to a string or buffer. So that, BOM mark (if any) and encoding header are to help a parser code that would do opposite thing: import that XML content into DOM model on another side.

Comment: You're right. It was the receiving side that was expecting it Unicode but from my testing I couldn't see what they were receiving. It was only after fiddling with encodings I was able to get it correct. So MSMQ wasn't at fault here.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the document encoding is (as long as it is declared correctly—_which is the job of an XML serializer_), the sequence of Unicode codepoints _represented_ will be the same. Note: `Encoding.Unicode` is the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set (long history behind that).

Comment: I think your xml declaration is saying 'utf-8'. It would be unwise to encode that with utf-16. Use Encoding.UTF8 instead.

Comment: The other side is expecting the string `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` exactly even though the encoding needs to be unicode. not much I can do there and I don't know why that is either.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the [note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx) in the documentation of the XmlDeclaration.

> Note: If the XmlDocument is saved to either a TextWriter or an XmlTextWriter, this encoding value is discarded. Instead, the encoding of the TextWriter or the XmlTextWriter is used. This ensures that the XML written out can be read back using the correct encoding.

Try this piece of code instead:

```
string xmlmsg = reqText.Text;
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlmsg);

using (Message _msg = new Message())
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(memStream))
{
     writer.WriteStartDocument(standalone: true);
     xdoc.WriteTo(writer);
     writer.Flush();
     memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     _msg.BodyStream = memStream;
     reqQueue.Send(_msg, "XML Request");
}
```

Comment: This includes the BOM before the XML which is causing issues over MSMQ since its not a file.

Comment: Use `new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding(false, false, true)` for UTF-16 (little endian) without BOM.

Comment: Including the BOM should not be a problem for any xml parser, even if it is 'not a file'. And MSMQ doesn't care which bytes you put on it. So your comment is not your issue.